# Angularjs .module not showing up in intellisense

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJs and this is my first code. I found an online 
tutorial where a module is declared like this

var myapp = angular.module('myApp',[])

When I type angular. , I am unable to get the .module to show up in my intellisense
but get $$modulename instead.

Am I doing something wrong? when I type in module the code actually runs.

Here is my code below.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>Practicing Angular</title>
            <script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Hello This is the first page</h1>    

            <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

                First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
                Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
                <br>
                Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
            </div>
            <script>
                var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
                app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
                    $scope.firstName = "John";
                    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
                });
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: What dotou mEan by not showing up

Comment: The .module did not show up in the intellisense when I type angular. ...

Answer (score 0):

try to link original angular.min.js instead,

```
<head>
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"> </script></head>
```

because its working in my VS 2012.

[printSceen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmyF0.png)

Comment: Thanks. I tried the original and same thing. I am not able to get the .module. Normally I don't think you can use the original in a production environment because you don't have any control over it. It is always recommended to use a local version

Comment: I know you to use local script its more secure. but just for testing i was saying to use link any ways.

Answer (score 0):

Download [angular.intellisense.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jmbledsoe/angularjs-visualstudio-intellisense/master/src/Scripts/angular.intellisense.js) and place it in your "Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\JavaScript\References" folder.

Using Nuget Package manager install AngularJS from [www.angularjs.org](http://www.angularjs.org)

Now add a reference to [angular.js](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js) or [angular.min.js](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.min.js) and your visual studio should have better support for AngularJS and you should start seeing intellisense.